# backbone option select works in Firefox, but not Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, backbone.js

I'm using Backbone to process clicks on options in a select box.  For some reason it works in Firefox, but not in Chrome.

It's not the "[using local files in Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40787&q=ajax%20local&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Feature%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone%20OS)" issue as this is all running on my server.

In the snippet below, the `FieldView` represents a single <option> in a select list.  In Firefox, clicking any of the options will run the `clicked()` function.  In Chrome, nothing seems to happen when I click any of the options.

```
var FieldView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "option",

    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    },
    events: {
        "click": "clicked"
    },
    clicked: function (e) {
        var a_display_name = this.model.get("display_name");
        var console_out = "selected " + a_display_name
        console.log(console_out);
        $("#fake_console").html(console_out);

    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.attr('value', this.model.get('COLUMN_NAME')).html(this.model.get('display_name'));
        return this;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thunderrabbit/QXAAW/3/

How can I get this to work in Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **on change**, [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/change/).

To access the model in FieldsView's collection, you should probably get the index of selected option by add a event to FieldsView:

```
events: {'change': 'optionChanged'},
optionChanged: function() {
    var index = this.$el.children('option:selected').index();
    var model = this.collection.at(index); // this is the model of the option view
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer!  I may select it if it works with fewer changes to my original code.  :-)

Comment: I just assumed that your collection and the select are sorted in the same order :).

Comment: Actually var index is always -1, no matter which option I select.  The options are in the same order, so this might actually work.

Comment: I had to use .find() instead of .children(), but this worked for me; thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Usually the option elements are the children of select element (and your FieldsView's el is 'select'?), this is the reason why I use .children().

Answer (score 1):

Here is an update jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phoenecke/QXAAW/4/

The `change` event is hooked up to the `<select>` element.  Then you can find the model using the value of the `<select>`.  Also, I added `idAttribute: 'COLUMN_NAME'` to the model, assuming that is the unique id.

```
        events: {
            "change": "changed"
        },
        changed: function (e) {
            // the select's val is the value of the selected option
            var id = this.$el.val();
            // find model in the collection
            var model = this.collection.get(id);
            var a_display_name = model.get("display_name");
            var console_out = "selected " + a_display_name
            console.log(console_out);
            $("#fake_console").html(console_out);

        },
```

Comment: Thanks for the updated fiddle!  I'm working on a different issue right now so I'll dig into your answer a bit later, but it appears you've got it sorted.  :-)

Comment: Natthakit's answer ended up working better for my situation.  :S